# Python class override

Tags: python, class, overriding, super

I am confused with a concept in python - base class overriding. I learned that you can have two different functions with the same name in different classes, and the correct function will be called on an object depending on which class the object is from.
However, I have just learned about the super call, and I learned that you can use it if you overrode (correct past tense?) a function that you need back. I'm confused because the overridden function isn't gone in the first place, is it? Why do I need to "restore" it using the super call?

Comment: This link might be helpful to understand method resolution order in Python. http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Answer (score 1):

The child's type is first in [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), so its method will get called even if any of its parents have the same method. `super` "restarts" MRO at the next link in the inheritance chain, and allows discovery of attributes belonging to parent classes.

Comment: I'm not sure what MRO is, but I kind of get what you're saying. After thinking about it, I think I have an answer (that a programming newbie like me gets), could somebody who knows this better tell me if this is correct?
An object from a derived class can only use the overridden function from the derived class. **super** allows the object to access the original function from the base class.

Comment: MRO is what the link in my answer describes.

Comment: I know, but I'm having a hard time understanding it because the only exposure to python I've had is codeacademy.